# Python: invalid syntax

Tags: python, linux

I have written a code and I am trying to run it with python version 3.9 and I am getting this error:

```
File "/home/user/hackthebox/blue/42315.py", line 928
def smb_send_file(smbConn, '/home/user/hackthebox/blue/eternalblue.exe', 'C', '/eternalblue.exe'):
```

This is the code:

Comment: (1) Fix your indentation; (2) post the actual error in full

Comment: If you want to have a default parameter you still have to assign it a ***name***.

Comment: Study: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-functions-define-and-call-a-function/  (or a similar tutorial of your choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have variables as arguments to a function. If you want to have variables with default values you just assign them on the function:

```
def smb_send_file(smbConn, path = '/home/user/hackthebox/blue/eternalblue.exe', lang = 'C', path2 = '/eternalblue.exe'):
```